# Passing a lambda to a secondary AppDomain as a stream of IL and assembling it back using DynamicMethod

Tags: c#, lambda, appdomain, cil, dynamic-method

Is it possible to pass a lambda expression to a secondary AppDomain as a stream of IL bytes and then assemble it back there using DynamicMethod so it can be called?

I'm not too sure this is the right way to go in the first place, so here's the (detailed) reason I ask this question...

In my applications, there are a lot of cases when I need to load a couple of assemblies for reflection, so I can determine what to do with them next. The problem part is I need to be able to unload the assemblies after I'm finished reflecting over them. This means I need to load them using another `AppDomain`.

Now, most of my cases are sort of similar, except not quite. For example, sometimes I need to return a simple confirmation, other times I need to serialize a resource stream from the assembly, and again other times I need to make a callback or two.

So I end up writing the same semi-complicated temporary `AppDomain` creation code over and over again and implementing custom `MarshalByRefObject` proxies to communicate between the new domain and the original one.

As this is not really acceptable anymore, I decided to code me an `AssemblyReflector` class that could be used this way:

```
using (var reflector = new AssemblyReflector(@"C:\MyAssembly.dll"))
{
    bool isMyAssembly = reflector.Execute(assembly =>
    {
        return assembly.GetType("MyAssembly.MyType") != null;
    });
}
```

`AssemblyReflector` would automize the `AppDomain` unloading by virtue of `IDisposable`, and allow me to execute a `Func<Assembly,object>`-type lambda holding the reflection code in another `AppDomain` transparently.

The problem is, lambdas cannot be passed to other domains so simply. So after searching around, I found what looks like a way to do just that: pass the lambda to the new `AppDomain` as an IL stream - and that brings me to the original question.

Here's what I tried, but didn't work (the problem was `BadImageFormatException` being thrown when trying to call the new delegate):

```
public delegate object AssemblyReflectorDelegate(Assembly reflectedAssembly);

public class AssemblyReflector : IDisposable
{
    private AppDomain _domain;
    private string _assemblyFile;
    public AssemblyReflector(string fileName) { ... }
    public void Dispose() { ... }

    public object Execute(AssemblyReflectorDelegate reflector)
    {
        var body = reflector.Method.GetMethodBody();
        _domain.SetData("IL", body.GetILAsByteArray());
        _domain.SetData("MaxStackSize", body.MaxStackSize);
        _domain.SetData("FileName", _assemblyFile);

        _domain.DoCallBack(() =>
        {
            var il = (byte[])AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("IL");
            var stack = (int)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("MaxStackSize");
            var fileName = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("FileName");
            var args = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
            var pars = new Type[] { typeof(Assembly) };

            var dm = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(object), pars,
                typeof(string).Module);
            dm.GetDynamicILInfo().SetCode(il, stack);

            var clone = (AssemblyReflectorDelegate)dm.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(AssemblyReflectorDelegate));
            var result = clone(args); // <-- BadImageFormatException thrown.

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("Result", result);
        });

        // Result obviously needs to be serializable for this to work.
        return _domain.GetData("Result");
    }
}
```

Am I even close (what's missing?), or is this a pointless excercise all in all?

NOTE: I realize that if this worked, I'd still have to be carefull about what I put into lambda in regard to references. That's not a problem, though.

**UPDATE: I managed to get a little further. It seems that simply calling `SetCode(...)` is not nearly enough to reconstruct the method. Here's what's needed:**

```
// Build a method signature. Since we know which delegate this is, this simply
// means adding its argument types together.
var builder = SignatureHelper.GetLocalVarSigHelper();
builder.AddArgument(typeof(Assembly), false);
var signature = builder.GetSignature();

// This is the tricky part... See explanation below.
di.SetCode(ILTokenResolver.Resolve(il, di, module), stack);
dm.InitLocals = initLocals; // Value gotten from original method's MethodInfo.
di.SetLocalSignature(signature);
```

The trick is as follows. Original IL contains certain metadata tokens which are valid only in the context of the original method. I needed to parse the IL and replace those tokens with ones that are valid in the new context. I did this by using a special class, `ILTokenResolver`, which I adapted from these two sources: [Drew Wilson](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ExpressionEval.aspx) and [Haibo Luo](http://blogs.msdn.com/haibo_luo/archive/2006/11/06/system-reflection-based-ilreader.aspx).

There is still a small problem with this - the new IL doesn't seem to be exactly valid. Depending on the exact contents of the lambda, it may or may not throw an InvalidProgramException at runtime.

As a simple example, this works:

```
reflector.Execute(a => { return 5; });
```

while this doesn't:

```
reflector.Execute(a => { int a = 5; return a; });
```

There are also more complex examples that are either working or not, depending on some yet-to-be-determined difference. It could be I missed some small but important detail. But I'm reasonably confident I'll find it after a more detailed comparison of the ildasm outputs. I'll post my findings here, when I do.

**EDIT:** Oh, man. I completely forgot this question was still open. But as it probably became obvious in itself, I gave up on solving this. I'm not happy about it, that's for sure. It's really a shame, but I guess I'll wait for better support from the framework and/or CLR before I attempt this again. There're just to many hacks one has to do to make this work, and even then it's not reliable. Apologies to everyone interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, because a lambda is more than just an expression in source code.  lambda expressions also create closures which capture/hoist variables into their own hidden classes.  The program is modified by the compiler so everywhere you use those variables you're actually talking to the class.  So you'd have to not only pass the code for the lambda, but also any changes to closure variables over time.

Comment: I was aware of that. But I thought that wouldn't be a problem if I didn't use outside variables in lambda?

How about if I used a plain old delegate instead of lambda?

Comment: Part of the point is that a lambda isn't just the code in the expression.  It also transforms other code in your app at compile time.  You can transfer compile-time changes to another, already compiled, assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve, but I made a component in the past that may solve it.

Basically, its purpose was to generate a Lambda Expression from a `string`. It uses a separate `AppDomain` to run the CodeDOM compiler. The IL of a compiled method is serialized to the original `AppDomain`, and then rebuild to a delegate with `DynamicMethod`. Then, the delegate is called and an lambda expression is returned.

I posted a full explanation of it on my [blog](http://jp-labs.blogspot.com/2008/11/dynamic-lambda-expressions-using.html). Naturally, it's open source. So, if you get to use it, please send me any feedback you think is reasonable.

Comment: I wanted to inject code from my AppDomain into my main VS extension AppDomain and this worked beautifully!


FYI to anyone else who wants to use this for existing code, you will need to make changes to rebuild the DynamicMethod from the MethodIL passing the module that contains all your types to avoid access/security exceptions.

Comment: @mstrange I'm glad to know this is still useful after more than 6 years.